# How to redirect root to sub-domain with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've a domain like example.com. I want to all the traffic on it to be sent to sub.example.com.

Currently I'm using this code but it sends to example.com/sub:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^sub
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: By **"I want to all the traffic on it to be sent to sub.example.com"**, do you mean you want requests to `example.com` be *redirected* to `sub.example.com`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to use the R flag: `Forces an external redirect, optionally with the specified HTTP status code.` [details...](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://... [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the following code in to your .htaccess file.

```
Redirect 301 / http://sub.domain.com
```

Remember to change http://sub.domain.com to your sub-domain.

Connor

Comment: @MoinUddin you cannot create external redirect without any changes in address bar.

Comment: You could do it with Mod_Rewrite though,

Comment: @ConnorGurney, just to clarify.  If you want the browser to cache the redirection, then you must use a 301.  An internal redirection using mod_rewrite will normally return a 200, but the browser will not be informed that rewriting has taken place.

Comment: @TerryR Please provide me some code to this with mod_rewrite.